# Can anyone tell me how I can fix this Gmail Email formatting issue?

Tags: email, formatting, gmail

I am creating a new template design for 1shoppingcart, but although the email is formatted correctly for most emails, on Gmail the format is slightly off. There is a grey horizontal line at the top and bottom, and in the email there are white squares that don't fit inside the lines of the email.

I read that I have to use tabling for Gmail emails. Does anyone know what the issue might be and/or any people who I could pay to fix this?

Thank you,

Conrad

Answer (score 2):

There are also a "soft cap" on the number of characters in a single line of HTML that can be submitted in email (it is around 700 characters). If a single line/element of markup exceeds that soft cap, it won't stop the email from being sent, but may cause some formatting breaks or other changes.

Remember that you don't need super flashy emails to make an impact, many people's mail clients (local, cloud, and webmail alike) are configured to reject graphics and other more advanced design techniques for security purposes. Keep your communications short and to the point and try to make it all fit as best as possible.

Also, with 1shoppingcart, you can set up a TEXT/HTML (MIME) email so in the event a customer could not read the email in HTML they could still view the text version.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article [design-guidelines](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/design-guidelines/) about designing html emails. Maybe it will help you.

Quote from article:

> Because clients like Gmail and Outlook
>   2007 have poor support for float,
>   margin and padding, you’ll need to use
>   tables as the framework of your email.

Comment: We did design with tables. Do you know of any other reasons why the emails might be off. Do you have any recommendations for people who could fix this?